# Is これから a fixed phase? What does it mean?

Tags: translation

I'm studying lessons 2 on Minna no Nihongo. There's a sentence says これから お世話になります and the phrase おねがいします。What do they mean?

Comment: First look it up in a dictionary and show us your guess about the meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it means
"from now on"
"here on in"
"after this"
"in the future"
etc

take your pick.

This sort of question really should answered for yourself by using a dictionary.

http://jisho.org/search/korekara